# Image Opacity, turn of and on

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have five images, when you click one of them I want that one to get full opacity while the other only gets half, to show it is the selected one.

I am using MVVM and generally wondering if I'm doing it the right way

I was thinking about passing the name of the imagesource binded into a property.

```
<StackLayout Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="0">
                            <Image Source="{Binding StatusUnresolved}" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                   VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="40" Opacity="{Binding StatusUnresolvedOpacity}">
                                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <!--<TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, Path=OnStatusTappedCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding StatusUnresolved}" />-->
                                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Image>
                        </StackLayout>
```

The list that turns the string into status later on.

```
  public List<IssueStatusModel> PossibleStatusValues
        {
            get
            {
                var items = new List<IssueStatusModel>
                {
                    new IssueStatusModel("statusUnresolved.png", IssueStatus.Unresolved),
                    new IssueStatusModel("statusInProgress.png", IssueStatus.InProgress),
                    new IssueStatusModel("statusDone.png", IssueStatus.Done)
                };

                return items;
            }
        }
```

Property for opacity

```
       public double StatusDoneOpacity
        {
            get { return statusDoneOpacity; }
            set
            {
                if (statusDoneOpacity != value)
                {
                    statusDoneOpacity = value;
                    NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(StatusUnresolvedOpacity));
                }
            }
        }

        public string StatusDone
        {
            get { return "statusDone.png"; }
        }

public void OnStatusTapped(string fileName)
        {
                foreach (IssueStatusModel item in StatusValues)
                {
                    if (item.Name != fileName) continue;
                    Issue.Status = item.Status;
                    StatusChecker();
                    return;
                }
            }

    }
```

Switch statement Changing all the opacities.

```
    private void StatusChecker()
            {
                switch (Issue.Status)
                {
                    case IssueStatus.Unresolved:
                        StatusUnresolvedOpacity = 1;
                        StatusInProgressOpacity = 0.5;
                        StatusDoneOpacity = 0.5;
                        StatusText = "Unresolved";
                        break;
                    case IssueStatus.InProgress:
                        StatusUnresolvedOpacity = 0.5;
                        StatusInProgressOpacity = 1;
                        StatusDoneOpacity = 0.5;
                        StatusText = "In Progress";
                        break;
                    case IssueStatus.Done:
                        StatusUnresolvedOpacity = 0.5;
                        StatusInProgressOpacity = 0.5;
                        statusDoneOpacity = 1;
                        StatusText = "Done";
                        break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: `having trouble to getting it to work` Tell us more...

Comment: Sorry, it works but seems to be a really crude way of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 2):

The way I'd attack this, if you have multiple images, create an `ImageVm` and encapsulate any image specific implementation details i.e. enum `State` and an `IsSelected` notification properties. Of course if you only have 1 image this becomes trivially easy and you don't need `vms`

Use a `DataTrigger` that binds to an `IsSelected` MVVM property to set the `Opacity` and state if you need to change the image source. Obviously on click you will need to set the `IsSelected` Property and deselect the other `VMs`

Example of `DataTrigger` for `IsSelected`

```
<Image Grid.Column="2" Stretch="None">
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Value="True" Binding="{Binding IsSelected}">
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.5"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

### Update

You CAN use triggers with enums, and you can use a tap recognizers to fire commands in your main viewmodals. also commands can take parameters as well.

It's probably better (knowing what you have described in the comments) to just make a State and Severity enum and bind to it, and set the State and Severity via a command by a gesture.

Then you could just make a Trigger for each Image to change the Opacity for each image on the various state and severity.

Comment: Yes! I got actually 3 images of status and 5 images of severity so this could be a better way to do it? So I should create an imageviewmodel class, but a bit unsure. How would I go set and unset the selected property in the imageVM? Sorry, bit new to this

Comment: So it this just one image control? with lots of images to change to?

Comment: What do you mean with Control? Is it the xaml part, a class or? I've just got more images as the xaml part, but with different source names.

Comment: @JsonDork i mean, how many images in your page? is it just one <image> or are there lots of them

Comment: There are 8 in total. 3 images of status and 5 of severity?

Comment: Ahh ok. i understand now

Comment: @JsonDork ive updated my answer, i dont have the time at the moment to flesh out a full example though, however someone else might give you a better example. Yet it should give you enough food for thought to research

Comment: Alright! Thanks a lot, I got no idea how to accomplish this but will attempt read up on datatriggers and see if I can handle it